# Setting context on custom listener in a dialog

Tags: java, android

I created a very simple listener interface that looks like this:

```
public interface ReportDialogListener {
    void shouldRemoveBlockedUser();
}
```

Now, in my ReportDialog class which is defined like this:

```
public class ReportDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {}
```

I want to implement this listener and send callback for a certain action. However, when I do send callback after a certain action... my mDialogListener variable is null.

Where do I set the context?

This is what I tried:

```
private ReportDialogListener mDialogListener;

@Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();


        try {
            mDialogListener = (ReportDialogListener) getContext();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        mDialogListener = null;
    }
```

But when I call `mDialogListener.shouldRemoveBlockedUser();`, `mDialogListener` is null...

Also- I made sure my main activity was implementing ReportDialogListener... thanks

Comment: can you show code for your custom dialog?

Answer (score 0):

If this main activity implements the interface, do not use the activity context. Use this instead. `mDialogListener = this;`

Also i do not see where you implement the interface,only the View onClick interface you have actually implemented.

```
public class ReportDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener
```

to

```
public class ReportDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener,ReportDialogListener
```

To implement the interface in another, either you define it in the constructor of the calling program, or devise a method that does it.

Comment: Remario, my `ReportDialog` needs to send a callback to another activity and all this does is send the callback to itself..

Comment: oh, you want the other activity to implement the listener and not this main actvity?

Comment: The `ReportDialog` is a supplementary class. It's called from my MainActivity `if (mReportDialog == null) {
            mReportDialog = new ReportDialog(this);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Implement Listener in MainActivity 


    Public class MainActivity implements ReportDialogListener {

    ReportDialogListener  reportDialogListener ;
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
    reportDialogListener =this;
    }

    @override
    public void shouldRemoveBlockedUser(){

    }

    }

Pass reportDialogListener  object to other class or activity and call the listener method reportDialogListener.shouldRemoveBlockedUser();
```

Comment: Prakash, little confused about this. I should pass the reportDialogListener to the dialog when I call it from the main activity?

Answer (score 0):

Since my main activity was actually sending `this` when creating an instance of `ReportDialog` :

```
if (mReportDialog == null) { 
      mReportDialog = new ReportDialog(this); 
}
```

I was able to assign it to a variable in the constructor of `ReportDialog`

```
public ReportDialog(Activity activity) {
        super(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
        init();
    }
```

Then, use it like this:

```
mDialogListener = (ReportDialogListener) mActivity;
```

Works perfectly.